# Handling WM_KEYDOWN in edit control on modal property sheet

Tags: c++, windows, atl, windows-messages, propertysheet

First of all: I'm using C++ and ATL+WTL.

I am trying to handle the `WM_KEYDOWN` for an edit control that is on a page of a *modal* property sheet. I'd like to get the `VK_NEXT` key while `VK_CONTROL` is down. Without success so far, I only get `VK_NEXT` if `VK_CONTROL` is not down. The *modal* property sheet seems to eat this combination, it is used to cycle through the tabs in a standard property sheet. I have already tried to let the edit control handle `WM_GETDLGCODE` and return `DLGC_WANTALLKEYS` but still don't get this combination. However if I use *modeless* property sheet everything works fine (property sheet does not handle <kbd>Ctrl+PageDown</kbd> and edit control receives those keys). In my application I don't want to make a *modeless* property sheet.

So the questions is: Is there any way to handle those keys (`VK_CONTROL` + `VK_NEXT`) in edit control placed on modal property sheet?